# Get Windows User of Impersonated Process

Tags: c#, impersonation

I am creating a new process under a different user using the CreateProcessWithLogonW method in a C# application which is functioning as a launcher.  In the impersonating process (which is also written in C#), I need to get the username of the original user who is logged into Windows (and not the username of the user who is being impersonated).  This is not an ASP application.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the 'GetWindowsSessionUsername' method in the following helper class, which gets the session id from the process id, and the username from the session id.

```
internal class WtsUtils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains values that indicate the type of session information to retrieve in a call to the <see cref="WTSQuerySessionInformation"/> function.
    /// </summary>
    private enum WtsInfoClass
    {
        /// <summary>A null-terminated string that contains the name of the initial program that Remote Desktop Services runs when the user logs on.</summary>
        WtsInitialProgram,
        /// <summary>A null-terminated string that contains the published name of the application that the session is running.</summary>
        WtsApplicationName,

        /// <summary>A null-terminated string that contains the default directory used when launching the initial program.</summary>
        WtsWorkingDirectory,

        /// <summary>This value is not used.</summary>
        WtsOemId,

        /// <summary>A <B>ULONG</B> value that contains the session identifier.</summary>
       WtsSessionId,

        /// <summary>A null-terminated string that contains the name of the user associated with the session.</summary>
       WtsUserName,

        /// <summary>A null-terminated string that contains the name of the Remote Desktop Services session.</summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// <B>Note</B>  Despite its name, specifying this type does not return the window station name.
        /// Rather, it returns the name of the Remote Desktop Services session.
        /// Each Remote Desktop Services session is associated with an interactive window station.
        /// Because the only supported window station name for an interactive window station is "WinSta0",
        /// each session is associated with its own "WinSta0" window station. For more information, see <see href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096(v=vs.85).aspx">Window Stations</see>.
        /// </remarks>
        WtsWinStationName,

        /// <summary>A null-terminated string that contains the name of the domain to which the logged-on user belongs.</summary>
        WtsDomainName,

        /// <summary>The session's current connection state. For more information, see WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS.</summary>
        WtsConnectState,

        /// <summary>A <B>ULONG</B> value that contains the build number of the client.</summary>
        WtsClientBuildNumber,

        /// <summary>A null-terminated string that contains the name of the client.</summary>
        WtsClientName,

        /// <summary>A null-terminated string that contains the directory in which the client is installed.</summary>
        WtsClientDirectory,

        /// <summary>A <B>USHORT</B> client-specific product identifier.</summary>
        WtsClientProductId,

        /// <summary>
        /// A <B>ULONG</B> value that contains a client-specific hardware identifier. This option is reserved for future use.
        /// <see cref="WTSQuerySessionInformation" /> will always return a value of 0.
        /// </summary>
        WtsClientHardwareId,

        /// <summary>The network type and network address of the client. For more information, see WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS.</summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The IP address is offset by two bytes from the start of the <B>Address</B> member of the WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS structure.
        /// </remarks>
        WtsClientAddress,

        /// <summary>Information about the display resolution of the client. For more information, see WTS_CLIENT_DISPLAY.</summary>
        WtsClientDisplay,

        /// <summary>
        /// A USHORT value that specifies information about the protocol type for the session. This is one of the following values:<BR />
        /// 0 - The console session.<BR />
        /// 1 - This value is retained for legacy purposes.<BR />
        /// 2 - The RDP protocol.<BR />
        /// </summary>
        WtsClientProtocolType,

        /// <summary>
        /// This value returns <B>FALSE</B>. If you call Marshal.GetLastError to get extended error information, <B>GetLastError</B> returns <B>ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED</B>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks><B>Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP:</B>  This value is not used.</remarks>
        WtsIdleTime,

        /// <summary>
        /// This value returns <B>FALSE</B>. If you call GetLastError to get extended error information, <B>GetLastError</B> returns <B>ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED</B>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks><B>Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP:</B>  This value is not used.</remarks>
        WtsLogonTime,

        /// <summary>
        /// This value returns <B>FALSE</B>. If you call Marshal.GetLastError to get extended error information, <B>GetLastError</B> returns <B>ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED</B>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks><B>Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP:</B>  This value is not used.</remarks>
        WtsIncomingBytes,

        /// <summary>
        /// This value returns <B>FALSE</B>. If you call Marshal.GetLastError to get extended error information, <B>GetLastError</B> returns <B>ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED</B>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks><B>Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP:</B>  This value is not used.</remarks>
        WtsOutgoingBytes,

        /// <summary>
        /// This value returns <B>FALSE</B>. If you call Marshal.GetLastError to get extended error information, <B>GetLastError</B> returns <B>ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED</B>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks><B>Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP:</B>  This value is not used.</remarks>
        WtsIncomingFrames,

        /// <summary>
        /// This value returns <B>FALSE</B>. If you call Marshal.GetLastError to get extended error information, <B>GetLastError</B> returns <B>ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED</B>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks><B>Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP:</B>  This value is not used.</remarks>
        WtsOutgoingFrames,

        /// <summary>Information about a Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) client. For more information, see WTSCLIENT.</summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// <B>Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP:</B>  This value is not supported.
        /// This value is supported beginning with Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista with SP1.
        /// </remarks>
        WtsClientInfo,

        /// <summary>Information about a client session on an RD Session Host server. For more information, see WTSINFO.</summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// <B>Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP:</B>  This value is not supported.
        /// This value is supported beginning with Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista with SP1.
        /// </remarks>
        WtsSessionInfo
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ProcessIdToSessionId(uint dwProcessId, out uint sessionId);

    [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
    private static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, WtsInfoClass wtsInfoClass, out IntPtr ppBuffer, out int bytesReturned);

    [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
    private static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pointer);

    public static string GetWindowsSessionUsername()
    {
        uint sessionId;
        ProcessIdToSessionId((uint)Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, out sessionId);

        return GetUsernameBySessionId((int)sessionId);
    }

    private static string GetUsernameBySessionId(int sessionId)
    {
        IntPtr buffer;
        int strLen;
        string username = "SYSTEM";
        if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr.Zero, sessionId, WtsInfoClass.WtsUserName, out buffer, out strLen) && strLen > 1)
        {
            username = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer);
            WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
        }
        return username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use P/Invoke to get the list of currently logged on users.  Remember in Windows, there can be more than 1 person logged into the machine at a time.  You will have to enumerate the list and pick the appropriate user.

[P/Invoke for NetWkstaUserEnum function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370669.aspx)

```
[DllImport("netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
    static extern int NetWkstaUserEnum(
       string servername,
       int level,
       out IntPtr bufptr,
       int prefmaxlen,
       out int entriesread,
       out int totalentries,
       ref int resume_handle);
```

Comment: Thanks, but then how can I select the appropriate user?

Comment: If it's a server there could be multiple users logged on.  If it's just a workstation, then there will probably only be 1, best to run it and see the result.